# Is there any free software for Oden's Ipop?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, spatial, software

I'm trying to use software that has an [Oden's Ipop Statistics](http://www.biomedware.com/files/documentation/clusterseer/Ipop/Ipop_Statistic.htm) function for testing spatial autocorrelation adjusted for population. I prefer knowing if something is available for FREE.

I have searched through the internet, but unfortunately I did not find nothing. I have one option for this, which is for me to use `R` and make a function of Oden's Ipop Statistics using the formula for it. But just in case someone knows of any free software for the Oden's Ipop, that would be a helpful to me with my research study.

Comment: I had a friend ask me the same question previously as well and I was never able to find one. The only software I know of is Biomedware's ClusterSeer program (not free).

Answer (score 4):

The GeoDa is free and you can do the Oden's Ipop